# Why aren't any callbacks hit in this Observable?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a function called loadBalls whose second argument takes in an observer.  When loadBalls is called passing a regular observer, that observer has it's onNext hit twice.  Because I'm only interested in the 2nd time it's hit, I pass in a AsyncSubject as an observer, and then after the loadBalls call subscribe to it.

```
secondsPassed = 0;
while(secondsPassed < 10) {
    try {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       secondsPassed++;
AsyncSubject<List<Ball> asyncSubj = AsyncSubject.create();
loadBalls(id, asyncSubj);
asyncSubj.subscribe(new Observer<List<Ball>>() {
                                @Override public void onCompleted() {
                                    boolean complete = true;
                                }

                                @Override public void         
                                onError(Throwable e) {
                                    boolean problem = true;
                                }

                                @Override public void  
                                    onNext(List<Ball> balls) {
                                    boolean next = true;
                                }
                              });
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```

None of the above callbacks get hit but I know the second onNext exists because if I simply do this onNext gets hit twice:

```
loadBalls(id, same_observer_instance_as_above)
```

The implementation of loadBalls is a blackbox I cannot see, I'd like to confirm my usage of AsyncSubject above.

Comment: Did you verify that the onCompleted() callback is called? I'm asking because the last() operator only emits an item upon completion of the stream (http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/last.html). If the onCompleted() is never called, last() won't emit as well.

Comment: I've since changed the subject to an AsyncSubject so that I don't need to call last().  The problem is surrounding the above code in a loop for some reason, I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: How does loadBalls() look like?